# React: setState with Countdown

Tags: reactjs, state, countdown, setstate

I have a state counter in my main App.js class. Also I have a Countdown.js, which updates the counter of his parent class every time he has finished. But i get an Error, when the timer finished once. Also, state counter jumps from 0 to 2 and not from 0 to 1...

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`).
```

How can i get rid of this error? Or do you have a solution how to count++, when the timer is finished?

My class App.js:

```
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"
import Countdown from "./Countdown.js"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
    this.count = this.count.bind(this);
  }

  count() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.counter++
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="window">
        <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
        <Countdown count={this.count} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

My Countdown.js

```
import React from "react";
import CountDown from "react-countdown";

class CountdownQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      time: 3000
    };
  }

  render() {
    const renderer = ({ seconds, completed }) => {
      if (completed) {
        this.props.count();
        return <h2>Zeit abgelaufen</h2>;
      } else {
        return <h3>{seconds}</h3>;
      }
    };

    return (
      <CountDown date={Date.now() + this.state.time} renderer={renderer} />
    );
  }
}

export default CountdownQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's exactly like the error says. You can't update state (like in your `count()` function) during a render. You're probably better of using the `onComplete` hook.

```js
class CountdownQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      time: 3000
    };
  }

  render() {
    // Removing this.props.count() from this function also keeps it more clean and focussed on the rendering.
    const renderer = ({ seconds, completed }) => {
      if (completed) {
        return <h2>Zeit abgelaufen</h2>;
      } else {
        return <h3>{seconds}</h3>;
      }
    };

    return (
      <CountDown
        date={Date.now() + this.state.time}
        onComplete={this.props.count} // <-- This will trigger the count function when the countdown completes.
        renderer={renderer}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Now the error is gone, but unfortunataly it only counts to 1 and then stops. 
Why does it not count more? It should, because when i change the state it should also rerender the Countdown

Comment: The `<Countdown />` doesn't restart because it is already mounted after the first time. In `<App />` you can add `key={this.state.counter}` to `<CountDown />` to actually remount it. Or you can add a ref to countdown component and use an onComplete to function to restart it like `onComplete = () => { this.props.count(); this.countdownRef.current.start();};`

Comment: Thank you with all my heart, you are simply amazing! 
Now everything works fine.